# Changing Display Refresh rate

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, 23.04

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 on a lenovo ideapad gaming 3 (AMD Ryzen 5 6600H + NVIDIA RTX 3050).
I often need to give presentations using a external projector, and it seems that Xorg cannot support different refresh rates the internal/external screens [without disabling compositor](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/yaatyo/psa_x11_does_support_mixed_refresh_rate_monitors/).

When I was on 22.10, I could simply change the refresh rate to suit the external display, but after the recent upgrade, the refresh rate is fixed at 120.21Hz and cannot be changed. This means that the external display cannot work at all. Switching to Wayland solves the problem, but this isn't always desirable as there are some bugs in Wayland (...plus I had to edit /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules to even enable Wayland).

I believe the problem is because the internal screen is only reporting a single refresh rate, and xorg will not use any refresh rate that is lower than what is reported (...even if they are valid). I've also seen [some guides](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789513/how-to-set-native-resolution-via-xorg-conf-overriding-edid) on disabling EDID. But...

- /etc/X11/xorg.conf doesn't exists, and generating one using "nvidia-xconfig" prevent Xorg from starting (...hangs immediately after login, and I haven't even edited the xorg.conf yet).
- None of the files in "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/" contains a "Device" section, and adding a "Device" section with just "Option "UseEdid" "False"" prevent Xorg from starting (...returns to the login screen after logging in).

Are there any ways to return to the 22.10 behavior of allowing refresh rate changes (...other than downgrading)?