# Refresh rate locked at 60hz on lenovo laptop

Tags: kubuntu, display, kde, lenovo, intel-graphics

I recently installed kubuntu 23.04 on [this](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/laptops/lenovo/lenovo_slim_series/lenovo-slim-7i-gen-8-(14-inch-intel)/83a40005us?cid=us%3Apaidsocial%3Aoajswv&source=Facebook&campaignid=23853123172700143&adsetid=23853123172740143&adid=23853123172850143&campaign_id=23853123172740143&ad_id=23853123172850143) laptop which supports 120hz on my laptop screen but in [display configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0HDt.png) it says it only supports 60hz. I tried wayland and x11.

This is the output of `sudo get-edid | parse-edid`:

```
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 7
No EDID on bus 8
No EDID on bus 9
No EDID on bus 10
No EDID on bus 11
No EDID on bus 13
No EDID on bus 14
No EDID on bus 15
No EDID on bus 16
1 potential busses found: 12
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 12
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier ""
        ModelName ""
        VendorName "CSO"
        # Monitor Manufactured week 0 of 2022
        # EDID version 1.4
        # Digital Display
        DisplaySize 300 190
        Gamma 2.20
        Option "DPMS" "false"
        Horizsync 229-229
        VertRefresh 40-120
        # Maximum pixel clock is 700MHz

        #Extension block found. Parsing...
I only know about extension blocks of type 02h. PLEASE email me!
Something strange happened. Please contact the author,
Matthew Kern at <pyrophobicman@gmail.com>
```

EDIT 1: Whenever I boot through recovery mode on X11 it says that 91hz is the only supported [refresh rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvHRq.png). When I restart and boot normally I can only select 60 hz.

Comment: Try setting your scale to 100% and see if it allows you to go to 120Hz.

Comment: @Terrance I tried 100% and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are using XOrg there might be a way of using the Horizsync and Vertrefresh https://askubuntu.com/a/789553/231142  Unfortunately, I am not going to be much more help beyond this since I don't have any 120Hz monitors to test with.  +1 to help with visibility and we can hope someone has an answer for you.